# Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined

Tags: reactjs

When I add more than two inputs i get an warning about controlled component changing to uncontrolled component. Also when you add value on the second input  the first input also gets inputted.

Warning :A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

```
import MyForm from './Components/MyForm';
import uniqid from "uniqid";

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      person: {
        firstName : '',
        secondName : '',
        profession : '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        phone:'',
        email: '',
        jobTitle: '',
        employer: '',
        startDate: '',
        endDate: '',
        schoolName: '',
        schoolLocation: '',
        gradStartDate: '',
        gradEndDate: '',
        id: uniqid()
        },
      resume:[]
      }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      person : {
        firstName: event.target.value,
        seconfName: event.target.value,
      }
    });
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return alert(this.state.person.firstName + this.state.person.secondName)
  }

  render () {
    const { person, resume} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      <MyForm person = {person} resume = {resume} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </div>
      
    )
  }
}


class MyForm extends React.Component {
    
    
    render() {
        const {person, handleChange,handleSubmit } = this.props;
        console.log(person,handleChange)
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit = { handleSubmit }>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            First Name:
                        <input type="text" value = { person.firstName }
                        onChange = { handleChange } name="firstName" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                                Second Name:
                            <input type="text" value = { person.secondName }
                            onChange = { handleChange } name="secondName" />
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type ="submit" value = "Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default MyForm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are affecting the same value to both `firstName` and `secondName`, you should handle the change of the first name separatly from the second name, and also you have a mistake of naming in `handleChange`, you are writing `seconfName` instead of `secondName`.

You can try this:

```
import MyForm from './Components/MyForm';
import uniqid from "uniqid";

class App extends Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
    person: {
        firstName : '',
        secondName : '',
        profession : '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        phone:'',
        email: '',
        jobTitle: '',
        employer: '',
        startDate: '',
        endDate: '',
        schoolName: '',
        schoolLocation: '',
        gradStartDate: '',
        gradEndDate: '',
        id: uniqid()
        },
    resume:[]
    }

    this.handleChangeFirstName = this.handleChangeFirstName.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeSecondName = this.handleChangeSecondName.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChangeFirstName = (event) => {
    this.setState({
    person : {
        ...this.state.person,
        firstName: event.target.value,
    }
    });
}

handleChangeSecondName = (event) => {
    this.setState({
    person : {
        ...this.state.person,
        secondName: event.target.value,
    }
    });
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return alert(this.state.person.firstName + this.state.person.secondName)
}

render () {
    const { person, resume} = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
    <MyForm person = {person} resume = {resume} handleChangeFirstName={this.handleChangeFirstName} handleChangeSecondName={this.handleChangeSecondName} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
    </div>
    
    )
}
}


class MyForm extends React.Component {
    
    
    render() {
        const {person, handleChangeFirstName, handleChangeSecondName,handleSubmit } = this.props;
        console.log(person,handleChange)
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit = { handleSubmit }>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                            First Name:
                        <input type="text" value = { person.firstName }
                        onChange = { handleChangeFirstName } name="firstName" />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>
                                Second Name:
                            <input type="text" value = { person.secondName }
                            onChange = { handleChangeSecondName } name="secondName" />
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    
                    <input type ="submit" value = "Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default MyForm;
```